# Does a basis of three vectors always span $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This may be a dumb question, but if I have three linearly independente vectors in $R^3$, will it always span $R^3$

I'm asking this because it's hard to visualize this for every vector. I can imagine particular cases but not the entire case. Is there a proof for it, or is this na observation?

Comment: Yes, because a maximal independent set = a basis = a minimal spanning set.

Comment: Yes. Almost by definition.

Comment: This is part of the definition of a basis, usually.  Is there some reason you think this might not be the case, or some reason it's hard to see this?

Comment: Make sure the three vectors you’re picturing point in three entirely different directions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it's because in the definition of a basis I Always read that it can span a subspace of $R^n$, not exactly span $R^n$

Comment: @MarterJs if the basis spans a subspace, then it is a basis of that subspace rather than a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  A basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yep, but I didn't find a proof that three linearly independente vectors in $R^3$ will always span $R^3$

Comment: @MarterJs see [the dimension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)

Comment: Also, see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a few ways to see this. The simplest is to note that if it didn't, there would be a fourth vector not in the span and therefore linearly independent of the other three, so you'd have four mutually linearly independent vectors, which is impossible in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: it's because in the definition of a basis I always read that it can span a subspace of $R^n$, not exactly span Rn

Comment: I don't understand. Every basis will span the entire vector space.